# My Website's Scrollable Divs Work Everywhere Except Mobile Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, scroll, safari

I'm working on a website, http://strange.business which is designed to load 5 random stories in 5 scrollable viewing divs. Note: There are only 2 stories right now.

There didn't appear to be any problem with that aspect of the page design, the divs would scroll without issue in Chrome, IE, Edge, etc. But I tried it on my gf's iPad Mini yesterday and the divs are locked for some reason. The stories do load, but they won't scroll.

The basic setup for those divs is thus:

```
#display1 {
background-color: white;
height: 350px;
overflow: auto;
}

#display1Inner {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: visible;

}

<div name="display1" id="display1" title="Display1">
        <span id="display1JavaWarning">You may need to enable 
            Javascript</span>           
        <object type="text/html" id="display1Inner"></object>
</div>
```

When the page loads, it executes a javascript function that picks a random preview htm file, and then populates the display1Inner object with that data. I'm aware that my coding could often be tighter, but it does generally work. Except on mobile Safari apparently.

I've tried a bunch of CSS variations after researching similar problems, but nothing seems to do the trick. That "overflow: visible;" bit was one of my latest attempts, but it wasn't present when I first noticed the problem. I don't know anybody with an iPhone (oddly enough) so I'm not sure if later versions of Safari still bug out on this, but the iPad I tested this on isn't that old. I should be able to make this work. Any thoughts?

PS. The page is still is a work in progress, sorry if you have a hard time navigating it.

**ETA:** Alright so I converted the page to use iframes inside nested divs, and now it works across platforms. So that much is solved. Yay!

Now though, I'm fiddling around trying to get rid of the double-scrollbars that appear when the page is viewed in desktop browsers. As I understand this workaround, IOS Safari totally disregards iframe height settings and displays them at full length. Hence the need for the iframe-wrapper div to keep that in check. And hence the extra scrollbar when I look at it in a "normal" browser window. If I disable scrolling on the iframe-wrapper div then it eliminates the double scrollbar, but also breaks scrolling in Safari.

You can view the most current incarnation at http://strange.business/test.htm. I'm open to suggestions.

**ETA:** Success! After setting the iframe heights to 99% and taking out the borders, they look just about like they did before, with no extra scrollbars. And scrolling works across platorms now. One less problem in the my life. Thanks for the help!

Comment: PS PS. Like I mentioned, there are only 2 stories out of 5 right now. Only the fully loaded stories will scroll. Thanks.

Comment: Created a stripped down, bare bones version of the div setup at http://strange.business/test2.htm. Tested it in Browserstack's simulated iPhone 6S and the story object still won't scroll. It's certainly an annoying problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following CSS for your div:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

I came across that solution in this codepen:
https://codepen.io/kristiegiles/pen/WveNaX?editors=110

It is set up to scroll an iframe, but I tried it with some plain html in place of the iframe and it worked on my iPhone.

The html is basically a div wrapped around your content:

```
<h1>scrolling on iOS</h1>
<div class="content">
<div class="iframe-wrapper">
// Your content here
</div>
</div>
```

With `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` and `overflow-y: scroll;` added to the class applied to the div:

```
html,body{
height:100%;
}
.content{
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}
.iframe-wrapper{
  position: absolute; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, I've incorporated that code into http://strange.business/test.htm and placed iframe-wrapper divs around each object. It gives me double scrollbars on each story, but otherwise it works fine in Chrome and on my S8. I can't test it on the iPad until I get home. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Hmm. I haven't gotten home yet, but I tested it on browserstack.com. The problem still occurred on the simulated iPhone6S when browsing to the test.htm page I created. Android devices run it fine. It's definitely weird.

Comment: Alright, I did finally manage to get it working in the 3rd pane of strange.business/test2.htm. It's basically the same scrolling iFrame setup being used on the example page you gave me. So I may have to convert my page to iFrames, but it's workable at least.

Comment: Well, glad it helped you to get something workable. I tested the code on my iPhone 6 and it seemed okay. Sorry the 6S was a problem. Good luck!

Comment: This is working great to make the scroll smooth but it also breaks the keyboard input when the keyboard is display on top of a scrollable section. Is there a way to fix this?